# Why does QFileDialog's selectedFiles method return an outdated list of files?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt4

I've sucessfully added a preview pane for scientific data to a `QFileDialog` by modifying the layout to include a pyqtgraph `PlotWidget`. I connected the `currentChanged` signal to a custom function that plots the data based on the file name it receives as an argument from the signal. That all works great.

Next I tried to see if I could plot multiple different files simultaneously. Since `currentChanged` only passes the most recently selected file, I attempted to grab the list of selected files using the `selectedFiles` method. I find that the list is always out of date: it contains all but most recently selected value. This feels like a bug...

I cannot, unfortunately, simply append the file name passed by `currentChanged` to the `QStringList` returned by `selectedFiles` since there are situations where this gives incorrect results: e.g. when I go from having eight files selected to only one.

Is there any way to force an update of the list of currently selected values?

Here is the code I'm currently fussing with. I'm using PyQt4 version 4.10.3 on Linux Mint 16.

```python
preview_dialog = QFileDialog()
preview_dialog.setFileMode(QtGui.QFileDialog.ExistingFiles)

def processFiles(filename):
    # The passed filename is always correct
    print filename

    # The following always returns an outdated list
    all_files = preview_dialog.selectedFiles()

    for f in all_files:
        do_something_with_my_file(str(f))

preview_dialog.currentChanged.connect(processFiles)
preview_dialog.exec_()
```

Any help is much appreciated.